# Filter for rows in pandas dataframe where values in a column are greater than x or NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to filter a pandas dataframe so that that the values in a certain column are either greater than a certain value, or are NaN. Lets say my dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1, 2, 3, 4], "col2": [4, 5, np.nan, 7]})
```

I've tried:

```
df = df[df["col2"] >= 5 | df["col2"] == np.nan]
```

and:

```
df = df[df["col2"] >= 5 | np.isnan(df["col2"])]
```

But the first causes an error, and the second excludes rows where the value is NaN. How can I get the result to be this:

```
pd.DataFrame({"col1":[2, 3, 4], "col2":[5, np.nan, 7]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try

```
df[df.col2.isna()|df.col2.gt(4)]



  col1  col2
1     2   5.0
2     3   NaN
3     4   7.0
```

Comment: FYI to anyone else out there, it looks like ```df['col2']``` works the same as ```df.col2```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can fill nan with the threshold:

```
df[df.fillna(5)>=5]
```